# Which Basis Set is suitable For Mercury-complex in DFT calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, basis-set

Which Basis Set is suitable For Mercury-complex in DFT calculations? Please provide the answers with any journal reference.

Comment: What research have you done on things far?

Comment: you should provide 1)package you are using 2)properties of interest 3)other atoms 4) size of the complex (ideally the structure too) 5) machine you are running it on.

Comment: Gaussian 09, optimization of mercury complex contains nearly 40 atoms..........cluster computer

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! Learn more about this site, taking the [tour] and visiting the [help]. Could you [edit] in an example of what you want to do. Is it a cluster of 40 Hg atoms or is it a cluster of 40 atoms containing one Hg? What are the other atoms? Does it have a charge? What DFT method would you like to do? What accuracy is necessary?